# PynamoDB: how to update an attribute in a ListAttribute of MapAttribute

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

I am learning how to use PynamoDB to work with AWS DynamoDB in my Python code. Here is what I have defined so far:

```
class OfficeEmployeeMap(MapAttribute):
    office_employee_id = NumberAttribute(hash_key=True)
    office_employee_direct_ids = UnicodeSetAttribute()

class Office(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'OfficeModel'
    office_id = NumberAttribute(hash_key=True)
    employees = ListAttribute(of=OfficeEmployeeMap)

Office.create_table(read_capacity_units=1, write_capacity_units=1)
```

Here is how I appended to the list of map attributes (`employees`):

```
emp1 = OfficeEmployeeMap(
    office_employee_id=111,
    office_employee_direct_ids={"222"}
)

Office(
    office_id=1
).update(
    actions=[
        Office.employees.set((Office.employees|[]).append([emp1]))
    ]
)
```

And here is what I am seeing in the newly created DynamoDB table `OfficeModel`:

[image]

Now I need to add another value, like `333`, to the set `office_employee_direct_ids` where `office_employee_id` == `111`, how can I do it with PynamoDB? Thanks for your help!

Comment: details in https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB/issues/813